# Changing font size on one line in multiline plot label in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, axis-labels

Is it possible to change the font size of one line of text in a multiline plot label using the ylabel command.  If so how?

PS:  I'm using Octave 5.2

I tried the code below but it gives me an error.

```
figure
plot((1:10).^2)
ylabel_txt1=strcat('1st line of text with smaller font') %1st line
ylabel_txt2=strcat('2nd line of text') %2nd line
ylabel({(ylabel_txt1,'fontsize',13) ;ylabel_txt2})
```

Comment: another option is to create a 'dummy' axes object, placed below, for the purpose of creating the desired label

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou sounds interesting I just have no idea what your referring to..`create a 'dummy' axes object, placed below`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ylabel` uses the `tex` interpreter by default, and `tex` interpreter allows changing the font size at arbitrary locations in the text using `\fontsize{size}`.

This is what you should be doing:

```matlab
ylabel({['\fontsize{13}', ylabel_txt1]; ['\fontsize{10}', ylabel_txt2]})
```

For other formatting options, you can take a look at the 'Text Properties' page in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment to an answer, since clarification was asked.
Hopefully the code is self-explanatory :)

```
ylabel_txt1 = '1st line of text with smaller font'; % 1st line
ylabel_txt2 = '2nd line of text';                   % 2nd line

F   = figure()
Ax1 = axes()
Ax2 = axes()

% create Ax2, make everything invisible except for ylabel
axes( Ax2 )
set( Ax2, 'color', 'none', 'xcolor', 'none', 'ycolor', 'none' )
ylabel( {ylabel_txt2, ' ', ' ', ' '}, 'fontsize', 16, 'color', 'k' );

% now 'create' Ax1 on top of Ax2
axes( Ax1 )
plot( (1:10) .^ 2 )
ylabel( ylabel_txt1, 'fontsize', 13 );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now :-)